# Setting PHP to use <?= instead of <?php echo

Tags: php

I've set up a new server and I don't know what setting to change to enable using `<?=$hello?>` instead of `<?php echo $hello ?>`.  It's probably simple, but I don't know the name of what I'm looking for to Google it.  PHP block shortcut settings?

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? `<?=` is available by default since PHP 5.4

Comment: That's the [short open tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php), a leftover of the XHTML fad.

Comment: I'm on PHP 5.4.27, but it's off for whatever reason.

Answer (score 5):

Set the following in your `php.ini`

`short_open_tag=On`

As mentioned in the comments, this practice is discouraged by some (including myself). Nevertheless, it's a matter of preference until it interferes with development, especially portability.

Comment: @Anthony no problem. For further research, they're typically called "short tags"

Comment: Note that "short open tags" are generally discouraged, because the server can get confused and mix them with other systems, such as XML. It's better to have the discipline to use the long form tags.

Comment: @Anthony You have to make sure to always use `<?php` open tags instead of short `<?` tags. Most of the server environment don't enable `short_open_tag` and your script will die.

Comment: They're discouraged for code you need to redistribute, because it requires a non-default setting. They're only a real issue when you want to embed PHP in XML documents.

Comment: But CI4 use this system. How about them?